# How to invoke a Java interface in Ruby as a proc

Tags: jruby

Id like the ability to pass an java implementation of some interface to Jruby and then use it as a proc. Unfortunately for me the examples show how one can wrap jruby classes into java interfaces but none that match my request.

A quick look at RubyProc seems like the obvious solution but i cant satisfy the Block requirement. The helpers JavaUtils, JavaUtilities and JavaEmbedUtils dont help as well.